# Is there a Genre key for music file in AVFoundation

Tags: swift, avfoundation

In short I'm using below code to get music song's metadata like artist name, album name, album cover. I'm wondering if there is genre key for music genres as Pop, Rock...?

And I found there is a key `iTunesMetadataKeyGenreID`, the context is all the songs is retrieved from documentDirectory(locally), could I use this one?

```
if let artist = metaData.first(where: { $0.commonKey == .commonKeyArtist }), let value = artist.value as? String {
    self.artist = value
} else {
    artist = "Unknown artist"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AVAsset` has multiple formats for metadata, you can access all of the formats available like this.

```
for format in asset.availableMetadataFormats {
    let metadata = asset.metadata(forFormat: format)
}
```

Please note that NOT ALL assets will have multiple formats (or even one) - so you need to account for that part.

Depending on which type of metadata your asset has, there  are few genre keys listed below.

1. [iTunesMetadataKeyPredefinedGenre](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatakey/1388214-itunesmetadatakeypredefinedgenre)
2. [quickTimeMetadataKeyGenre](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatakey/1388748-quicktimemetadatakeygenre)
3. [quickTimeUserDataKeyGenre](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatakey/1388807-quicktimeuserdatakeygenre)
4. [metadata3GPUserDataKeyGenre](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatakey/1387245-metadata3gpuserdatakeygenre)

Comment: Thanks. When I print things in Xcode, I found `commonKeyType` is the one to fetch genre type in metadata. My bad, I'm too lazy to try it first myself.